# Is there any chance to use Ubuntu with a live USB pen drive on my MacBook Pro 2018 with touchbar?

Tags: live-usb, mac, macbook-pro

I have followed correctly the tutorial about flashing ubuntu on a usb stick with mac os. I can run the operating system but, obviously, nothing works. Can I install driver for trackpad and keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

A [Google Search for this problem](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=macbook%20pro%202018%20ubuntu&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=y&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) revealed a kernel patch [has been published for the Touchbar](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/71#issuecomment-507325112). However, patching the kernel used in a LiveUSB is highly problematic, and you would be better off installing Ubuntu into the USB as if you were installing to an SSD, from a different LiveUSB, then patching the kernel on the non-Live USB.